# How to remove value if value have different value between column A and B

Tags: mysql

I have some trouble, when I want make some validate the query isn't display my expectation table, so I want make some value but if the value in field `A` and `B` is different then value of table related to field `B` will be `NULL`.

my expectation table like this :

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
+  no_reg   +     date_time_A     +   time_in   +   time_out  +  B.date_time date_time_B  +
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
+  2019069  + 2020-05-04 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   21:15:00  +    2020-05-04 21:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-04 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   28:15:00  +    2020-05-04 28:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-04 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   27:15:00  +    2020-05-04 27:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-05 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   21:15:00  +    2020-05-05 21:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-06 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +     NULL    +           NULL            +
+  2019069  +        NULL         +    NULL     +   23:15:00  +    2020-05-07 23:15:00    +
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

but in reality code result is :

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
+  no_reg   +     date_time_A     +   time_in   +   time_out  +  B.date_time date_time_B  +
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
+  2019069  + 2020-05-04 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   21:15:00  +    2020-05-04 21:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-04 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   28:15:00  +    2020-05-04 28:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-04 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   27:15:00  +    2020-05-04 27:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-05 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   21:15:00  +    2020-05-05 21:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-05 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   23:15:00  +    2020-05-07 23:15:00    +
+  2019069  + 2020-05-06 07:15:00 +  07:15:00   +   23:15:00  +    2020-05-07 23:15:00    +
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

for database structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `raw_attendance` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`no_reg` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`time` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `raw_attendance` (`id`, `no_reg`, `date_time`, `time`) VALUES
(115, '2019069', '2020-05-04 07:15:00', '07:15:00'),
(116, '2019069', '2020-05-04 21:15:00', '21:15:00'),
(117, '2019069', '2020-05-05 03:15:00', '03:15:00'),
(118, '2019069', '2020-05-05 04:15:00', '04:15:00'),
(119, '2019069', '2020-05-05 07:15:00', '07:15:00'),
(120, '2019069', '2020-05-05 21:15:00', '21:15:00'),
(121, '2019069', '2020-05-06 07:15:00', '07:15:00'),
(123, '2019069', '2020-05-07 23:15:00', '23:15:00'),
(124, '2019070', '2020-05-04 07:25:00', '07:25:00'),
(125, '2019070', '2020-05-04 21:25:00', '21:25:00'),
(126, '2019070', '2020-05-05 03:35:00', '03:35:00'),
(127, '2019070', '2020-05-05 04:25:00', '04:25:00'),
(128, '2019070', '2020-05-05 07:55:00', '07:55:00'),
(129, '2019070', '2020-05-05 21:55:00', '21:55:00');
```

query that I use for reality result is :

```
SELECT A.id, A.no_reg, A.date_time date_time_A, A.time time_in, 
CASE
   WHEN B.time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN B.time
   WHEN B.time BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' THEN TIMEDIFF(B.time, "-24:00:00")
END time_out, B.time test, B.date_time date_time_B
FROM raw_attendance A
LEFT JOIN raw_attendance B
  ON A.no_reg = B.no_reg
    AND A.date_time < B.date_time
WHERE A.time BETWEEN '06:14:00' AND '11:59:00' AND A.`no_reg` = '2019069'
HAVING 
CASE
  WHEN B.time BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' OR B.time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN 1
  WHEN A.date_time <> B.date_time THEN 0 ELSE 1
END
ORDER BY A.`date_time` ASC
```

And for testing editor : [MySQL Query Editor In db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rH5jGBT8x3o5HUpqbRVfaJ/4)

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: Note that it's exceptionally rare to use HAVING except in conjunction with a GROUP BY clause

Comment: is that a good query? If not I will change it again to get better results

Comment: Your code suggest that you have time ranges for deciding time_in and time_out but why does (117, '2019069', '2020-05-05 03:15:00', '03:15:00') and (118, '2019069', '2020-05-05 04:15:00', '04:15:00') not appear in your exceptions, Also you appear to suggest that  paired rows represent time in/time out unless second row does not have a time out value on the same day or before 00:06:14 next day?

Comment: time range what I have is in `time_in` have range `'06:15:00' - '11:59:00'` and then for `time_out` have range `'12:00:00' - '23:59:00'` (same day) and second range `'00:00:00' - '06:14:00'` (another day) but If I have condition like date `(117, '2019069', '2020-05-05 03:15:00', '03:15:00') and (118, '2019069', '2020-05-05 04:15:00', '04:15:00')` the value will be combined in the `time_in` field which has a `date` in `'2020-05-04'`, and I have condition too when `time_out` between `'00:00:00' AND '06:14:00'` the time will be plus using `TIMEDIFF("-24:00:00")`, to make easier when compare time